# Find plane of symmetry (knowing reflection positions)

Tags: symmetry, kinematics

I have a set of 3 distincts points which I know the positions in 3D (say D1, D2, D3).

I also know they are the plane-symmetry of 3 other distinct points in 3D (say B1, B2, B3)  which I also know the positions (paired in same notation order).

Regarding the plane of symmetry, all I know is 1 point position (say C).

And what I'm looking for is of course the plane normal (say n=(nx, ny, nz)).

So far I was thinking of iterating to find the plane normal but maybe there is a direct way to resolve for it, no?

NB: I perfectly know the positions of points (up to numerical precision for double), i.e. I'm not trying on a blurry acquired positions, I'm trying to solve inverse kinematic of a robot.

Comment: This is confusing..... you know the points $D_1,D_2, D_3$ which define a plane(lets call the plane $D$) and 3 other points ($B_1,B_2,B_3$) which define the plane $B$ and you want to know an equation for $B'$ the plane $B$ reflected across $D?$   Not sure where $C$ fits into this.

Comment: The three midpoints of the segments $B_iD_i$ lie on the plane of symmetry. That's enough information to find the equation of the plane.

Comment: @user317176 - No, I think $D_i$ is the reflection of $B_i$ in an unknown mirror plane passing through $C$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Those midpoints are on the plane. The fact that it should contain $C$ is a fourth point, which may or may not be coplanar with the midpoints.

Comment: @mr_e_man it's indeed correct description B and D are mirrors in an unknown plane passing through C ... Making drawings in 2D, Ethan Bolker answer seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any single reflected pair $BD$ determines the plane of reflection, since the plane is perpendicular to $BD$ and passes through the midpoint of that segment.

So you have three segments that must be parallel and four points (three midpoints, and $C$) that must all lie on the same plane. That's a good check on your data.

Comment: Hummm... I made drawing in 2D and indeed seems as simple as this... I'm struggling right now to clearly visualize in 3D but sounds reasonable it will generalize. I'll further double check tomorrow from direct kinematic I already wrote in matlab before to validate your answer. Thank you.

Comment: This works... I lied a little regarding B points which I only know up to a rotation angle but now it's easy to screw this angle as I know point C lies in the plane of symmetry.